# Problems with images when trying to make a website responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, web, responsive

I took a course in Codeacademy.com for interactive website and finished it, the website we built was not responsive so i took on myself to take it and try to make it a responsive one.
I am having a problem right now with the images on the slider,they just go out of the div,how can i make them stay there?

links:
[HTML](http://pastebin.com/S8GA88iT)
[CSS](http://pastebin.com/Pmj3ABXt)

```css
/* General */

.container {
  width: 70%;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 1% 2% 1% 1%;
}


/* Menu */ 

.header .menu {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
}

.menu > li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 3% 0 1.5%;
}

.menu a {
  color: #898989;
}

/* Dropdown */

.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  min-width: 95px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #898989;
  padding: 8%;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/* Carousel */

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 470px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.slide {
  background: transparent url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/feature-gradient-transparent.png') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.active-slide {
    display: block;
}

.slide-copy h1 {
  color: #363636;  
  
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.slide-copy h2 {
  color: #b7b7b7;
  
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 2%;
}

.slide-copy p {
  color: #959595;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.slide-img {
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

/* Slide feature */

.slide-feature {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ac.png');
  height: 470px;
}

.slide-feature img {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.slide-feature a {
  display: block;
  color: #6fc5e0;
  
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueMdCn", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  
  font-size: 20px;
}

.slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
}

.arrow-prev {
  margin-right: 2.8%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 0.7%;
}

.arrow-next {
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 0.7%;
}

.slider-dots {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.slider-dots li {
  color: #bbbcbc;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.slider-dots li.active-dot {
  color: #363636;
}

/* App links */

.get-app {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
}

.get-app li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.get-app img {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="logo-icon">
          <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/logo.png">
        </a>

        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Get the App</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Magazines</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Tools</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">More <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Our Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Maps Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Eng Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Advertisers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Publishers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">

      <div class="slide active-slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>Flipboard Is Your Personal Magazine</h1>
              <p>It's a single place to discover, collect and share the news you care about.  Add your favorite social networks, publications and blogs to stay connected to the topics and people closest to you.</p>
              
              <ul class="get-app">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
              <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/home.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div>

      <div class="slide slide-feature">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/cnn.png"></a>
              <a href="#">Read Now</a>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div> 

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>Enjoy Flipboard Magazines</h1>
              <h2>on the Web</h2>
              <p>Millions of people use Flipboard to read and collect the news they care about, curating their favorite stories into their own magazines on any topic imaginable. Now magazines created by our readers, from Dali to End Trafficking, can be shared and enjoyed on the Web by anyone, anywhere.</p>
              
            </div>
            <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
              <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/magazines.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div> 


      <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>Badges & Widgets</h1>
              <p>Millions of people use Flipboard to read and collect the news they care about, curating their favorite stories into their own magazines. Now you can promote the ones you create or think are awesome.</p>
              
              <ul class="get-app">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
              <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/bw.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div> 

    </div>

    <div class="slider-nav">
      <a href="#" class="arrow-prev"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-prev.png"></a>
      <ul class="slider-dots">
        <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="arrow-next"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-next.png"></a>
    </div> 
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello , the best way to show code snippets is to use something like jsfiddle.net/ or codepen.io or you can even use stack overflows own code inserting tool.

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot

Comment: img { max-width:100% }

Comment: Not working,already tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap, you can use class img-responsive in the image tag to make your images responsive.

```
<div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/home.png">
</div>
```

your HTML will be like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="logo-icon">
          <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/logo.png">
        </a>

        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Get the App</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Magazines</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Tools</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">More <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Our Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Maps Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Eng Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Advertisers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Publishers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">

      <div class="slide active-slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>Flipboard Is Your Personal Magazine</h1>
              <p>It's a single place to discover, collect and share the news you care about.  Add your favorite social networks, publications and blogs to stay connected to the topics and people closest to you.</p>

              <ul class="get-app">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/home.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div>

      <div class="slide slide-feature">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/cnn.png"></a>
              <a href="#">Read Now</a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>      
      </div> 

      <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>Enjoy Flipboard Magazines</h1>
              <h2>on the Web</h2>
              <p>Millions of people use Flipboard to read and collect the news they care about, curating their favorite stories into their own magazines on any topic imaginable. Now magazines created by our readers, from Dali to End Trafficking, can be shared and enjoyed on the Web by anyone, anywhere.</p>

            </div>
            <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/magazines.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div> 


      <div class="slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>Badges & Widgets</h1>
              <p>Millions of people use Flipboard to read and collect the news they care about, curating their favorite stories into their own magazines. Now you can promote the ones you create or think are awesome.</p>

              <ul class="get-app">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/bw.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div> 

    </div>

    <div class="slider-nav">
      <a href="#" class="arrow-prev"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-prev.png"></a>
      <ul class="slider-dots">
        <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="arrow-next"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-next.png"></a>
    </div> 

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for making any image auto responsive do

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
```

Now image will be display according to its parent width.

thanks

Comment: Hi, the picture is still out of the div.

Answer (score 0):

As your using bootstrap, you can use the class ".img-responsive", e.g :

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/logo.png">
```

Comment: Still the image is out of boundaries,in the code we made on course we added width to the image on the img link like this:
 <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/home.png" width="540px">

Comment: I don't get it .. Which slider are you talking about ? The slider is not working on your fiddle.

Comment: its not working because the picture is disabling it because it goes out of the div